# How to apply functions/formulas from last row after inserting a new row to google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i am inserting 2 columns data into a google spreadsheet . My sheet has 3 column A,B and C . Column A,B data is inserted via form but column C data is inserted via formula =HTTPResponse() . How i can copy this formula to new row on column C when new data inserted via form using following code? currently my code doesn't copy the code to new row!

insert code:

```
function doPost(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('active'));
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; //read headers
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // get next row
  var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
  var col = 0;


for (i in headers){ 
    if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){
      val = new Date();
    } else if (headers[i] == "HTTPResponse"){ // (based on the assumption you add a column to you sheet with this name
      val = '=HTTPResponse(B'+(nextRow+1)+')';
    } else {
      val = e.parameter[headers[i]];
    }
    cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
    col++;
  }

  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  for( p in e.parameters){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(p +" "+e.parameters[p]));
  }
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function setUp() {
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('active', SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

// i want to apply this next formula to new row:

```
unction HTTPResponse( uri )
{
var response_code ;
try {
response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
}
catch( error ) {
response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (ddd)./ )[1] ;
}
finally {
return response_code ;
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried using this line "cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue('=HTTPResponse()');" since the variable 'col' got incremented,  I think you can add that line after the for loop and it will add the formula in column C. check it to see how if it works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added your line after cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val); and i got "undefined" value in column c ! how i can fix that ?

Comment: did you also add a url?  the function HTTPResponse is expecting a url so it can call it with the URLFecht.fetch function.

Comment: i have a form that i always pass to sheet a url and name . The url and name got inserted into sheet successfully but on column C instead of server status i got "undefined" value. I think i should pass pass column id for exam =HTTPResponse(B4) as well. how to pass each cell id ?

Comment: I even typed the column id before inserting in to line but didn't work(cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue('=HTTPResponse(B4)');)

Comment: try running just the HTTPResponse giving it the url you are using or something generic like www.google.com and try to debug it. i'm using your code and if i give a valid url it works fine but if i give an invalid one, the cell is just empty. i never receive 'undefined'

Comment: i tried     cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue('=HTTPResponse(http://www.cnn.com)'); and get undefined on the c column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91414/discussion-between-gerardo-and-user1788736).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the code is to cycle through the sheet headings to match the passed parameter. If a column heading isn't found then `val` is `undefined`. The solution would be to have a named column for the formula and create another exception similar to timestamp e.g.:

```
  for (i in headers){ 
    if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){
      val = new Date();
    } else if (headers[i] == "HTTPResponse"){ // (based on the assumption you add a column to you sheet with this name
      val = '=HTTPResponse(B'+(nextRow+1)+')';
    } else {
      val = e.parameter[headers[i]];
    }
    cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
    col++;
  }
```

If for performance reasons you'd prefer to run `HTTPResponse()` when a new value is submitted and return a static value instead of setting the variable `val` to a formula you can get the `HTTPResponse()` value by replacing the line with:

```
  // assuming that url is the name of the POST value with the url
  val = HTTPResponse(e.parameter.url);
```

Here is a copy of [a Google Sheet which implements both methods](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inGcO3EWhvW03PVR4h44EkisvC5DgD1xoHhTYvnW_AM/edit#gid=0) (File > Make a copy to see the open Tools > Script editor)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I named column C as HTTPResponse as you suggested and used the code 
you posted i still get udefined in new row(column C) when data get inserted into the row!
is there away to refrence value of url(inside the google script) not from sheet cell but from post 
method and run httresponse and place its value to column c ? is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: @user1788736 I've updated the answer to include how to get the static value into the cell and an example Google Sheet which implements both methods (remember to File > Make a copy to see the Tools > Script editor code)

Comment: @user1788736 .. also remember when you update your code you need to publish a new version or the app won't use your edits unless in dev mode

Comment: Thanks for updating the code . I tried your script it worked but after adding extra column for url name value on column C now i get undefined on E! where in the code should i define the number of columns ? A(timestamp),B(url),c(urlname),d(httpresponse formula) and E(httresponse static)

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a urlname value in the post payload? It'll be case and space sensitive.  http://hurl.it is what I use for testing

Comment: Thanks everything is working i had to run setup first then publish a new version . for some strange reason script editor was not running my edited code even i was saving the changed but i had to publish as new to fix it!